# Very weird Make behavior on linux when specifying directory dependency to a percent rule

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I observe the following very strange behavior of a simple makefile:

For a C project let's say I have n>=2 .c files to compile in a directory.

For example assume you have a.c and b.c to compile

My makefile is:

```
OBJDIR = obj

all: $(OBJDIR)/a.o $(OBJDIR)/b.o
$(OBJDIR):
        mkdir $(OBJDIR)
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(OBJDIR)
        gcc -c $< -o $@
```

So it requires that a.o and b.o be compiled and put in a new folder obj.
I want to do that because I find it messy to have .c and .o files in the same folder. Moreover I want to create the folder if it does not exist because when I upload the project with git for some reason it does not keep track of empty folders.

On my windows machine it works fine and does what I want.

```
make
mkdir obj
gcc -c a.c -o obj/a.o
gcc -c b.c -o obj/b.o
make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

However on my linux machine it does the following:

```
make
mkdir obj
gcc -c a.c -o obj/a.o
gcc -c b.c -o obj/b.o
make
gcc -c a.c -o obj/a.o
make
gcc -c b.c -o obj/b.o
make
gcc -c a.c -o obj/a.o
make
gcc -c b.c -o obj/b.o
```

I only ran make command here. other lines are make's job. I find that cycling behavior quite annoying.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your Make rule wants the directory to be **older** than the .o file.

But when you compile the object and put it into the directory, the directory is updated, and becomes newer than the .o file.

So:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(OBJDIR)
```

sees a %.o which is *stale*, and reacts.

I remember there was an elegant workaround, but a quick fix should be

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(OBJDIR)
gcc -c $< -o $@
touch $@
```

Comment: "there was an elegant workaround". You may be thinking of [order only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)